# ROS Answers SE migration: uninstall ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I installed Ros some months ago because gazedo direct installation gave me many problem. So i installed Gazebo using the "ros users procedure". Now I would to uninstall ros in order to try again installing gazebo directly. When i type the comand: sudo apt-get remove ros , but it was not able to finde the packege.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45218/uninstall-ros/) by [tommy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3100/tommy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name of the package includes the distro name.
So try:

```
 $ sudo aptitude remove ros-electric-ros
```

and/or

```
 $ sudo aptitude remove ros-fuerte-ros
```

You can see what is installed by running

```
$ aptitude search ros-
```

Those with a small i at the beginning of the line are installed.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4